# Plot all the years mentioned in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, linegraph

I have a dataframe with a column of year and another column which consists of the frequency count of the years.
My dataframe looks like the following

`year <- c(2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022)` 
`freq <- c(3, 12, 16, 11, 36, 32, 20, 30 ,41, 33)` 
`df <- data.frame(year, freq)`

I am trying to plot a line graph using ggplot. But all the years are not getting plotted on x-axis. I want all the years in the "year" column to get plotted on the x-axis and their respective frequencies on the y-axis. Please give me a solution to this problem

Thank you.

Comment: Please include the code you are using to plot. I suspect you need to add `+ `[`scale_x_continuous`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html)`(breaks = 2013:2022)`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! I will edit my post and add the whole code.

Comment: base_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x =year, y = freq))+ 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2013:2022)   ##this is the accurate code. This code plotted the required graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a wider range of years or need to reuse the code for other plots, then you can use `max` and `min` on years.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = freq)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(min(df$year):max(df$year))) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Frequency")
```

Or as @r2evans suggested, you can also directly provide the years too.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = freq)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2013:2022)) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Frequency")
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Your first code will only work if you have defined both the columns as individual objects (i.e., `year`) *and* the data.frame, and I argue that while that "technique" is taught in many classes, it is not good to assume that. The `breaks=` does not use non-standard evaluation of the frame, so for me `min(year)` fails.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, I typically do not use it, but can be helpful if needing to plot similar dataframes. However, I do realize that I forgot to add `df$.`, so have added that (it was unintentional and ran in my environment since I had explicitly created a variable called `year`).

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make, especially with so many of the new-to-R questions on SO; I do it periodically and face-slap when I see what I've done.